# Use smoothScrollTo in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-scroll

I have following situation:

I'm using a Navigation Drawer to make the user easily navigate between different topics.

You can find a picture here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2gMUEFwlGRfSHRzVlptYmFQTXc/edit?usp=sharing

When clicking on a heading, like **General** the only the main content view is replaced, by using a fragment and a layout file.
But when the user clicks on a subheading, like **Gameplay**, the layout changes, AND it should scroll down to a specifc view in the layout.

So in my fragment class I'm using the "onViewCreated" method and the smoothScrollTo method, provided by a ScrollView. The ScrollView and the RelativeLayout are both not null, and set to the right id, set in "onCreateView"

Codesnippets:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_BOOL)) {
        scrollView = (ScrollView)getView().findViewById(scrollID);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)getView().findViewById(relativeID);

        ((ScrollView)getView().findViewById(scrollID)).smoothScrollTo(
                0, (getView().findViewById(relativeID)).getLeft());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SCROLL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).                  
                show();
        }
     }
```

The problem is that it is not executing the "smoothScrollTo" method, while the toast gets executed.

Here I call the fragment (boolean scroll is used to control the smoothScrollTo method):

```
private void selectItem(int Id, boolean scroll) {
    Fragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean(ContentFragment.ARG_BOOL, scroll);
    args.putInt(ContentFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, Id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(Id);
    getActionBar().setTitle(textView.getText());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Thanks for your help ;-)

**EDIT:** 
***SOLUTION:***

```
if (getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_BOOL)) {
    getView().findViewById(scrollID).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((ScrollView) getView().findViewById(scrollID)).
                smoothScrollTo(0, (getView().findViewById(relativeID)).getTop());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try calling [`smoothScrollTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo(int,%20int)) method in calling `post` of the view:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)getView().findViewById(scrollID);
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,(getView().findViewById(relativeID)).getTop());
    }
});
```

Comment: the method smoothScrollTo cant be found anymore, after using in **.post**, but, a new thread could be the solution!
Look in the edit above, but thats also not working :/

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! you just made my day, no, my WEEK!

Comment: the mistakte we both, escpecially I, made is the get left, for the y coordinate .. it has to be getTop! but thanks mate!